# ActiveMQ failover not working as expected

Tags: java, activemq-classic, failover

Good day

I am using ActiveMQ 5.7 in a standalone configuration.  I have a server application that has an embedded broker.  The server "produces" tasks and places them on a persistent queue.

One or more clients are connecting to the broker running in the server application and "consuming" jobs.  I am using the following connection string to connect to the broker:

```
failover:(tcp://0.0.0.0:61616)?maxReconnectAttempts=-1
```

The behaviour I am getting is the following:

If the client is started up first, it tries to connect to the server continuously (with incremental backup, etc.) and behaves exactly as expected.

If the server is than started up, the client connects successfully and everything works well.

If the server is now terminated, the client logs the lost connection and retries to connect as before.  However, it only reties to connect 10 times and then terminates.  I don't understand this behaviour as -1 means infinite.  If I change the -1 to, say, 5, the client attempts 5 times to reconnect and then terminates (as expected).  Any amount above 10 is simply ignored.  It is as if 10 has become this magical barrier.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would test against a later ActiveMQ release and see if it's a bug that's since been fixed